# How to make line to curve shape to fill the image

Tags: android, progress-bar

[image]

I used square progress bar library from [Github android square progress bar](https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar), everything is working fine but i want to make the bar should fill my image.. anyone having idea regarding this.???

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import net.yscs.android.square_progressbar.utils.CalculationUtil;
import net.yscs.android.square_progressbar.utils.PercentStyle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class SquareProgressView extends View {

    private double progress;
    private final Paint progressBarPaint;
    private final Paint outlinePaint;
    private final Paint textPaint;

    private float widthInDp = 10;
    private float strokewidth = 0;
    private Canvas canvas;

    private boolean outline = false;
    private boolean startline = false;
    private boolean showProgress = false;

    private PercentStyle percentSettings = new PercentStyle(Align.CENTER, 150,
            true);
    private boolean clearOnHundred = false;

    public SquareProgressView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        progressBarPaint = new Paint();
        progressBarPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
        progressBarPaint.setStrokeWidth(CalculationUtil.convertDpToPx(
                widthInDp, getContext()));
        progressBarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        progressBarPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        outlinePaint = new Paint();
        outlinePaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        outlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        outlinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outlinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    }

    public SquareProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        progressBarPaint = new Paint();
        progressBarPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
        progressBarPaint.setStrokeWidth(CalculationUtil.convertDpToPx(
                widthInDp, getContext()));
        progressBarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        progressBarPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        outlinePaint = new Paint();
        outlinePaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        outlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        outlinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outlinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    public SquareProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        progressBarPaint = new Paint();
        progressBarPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
        progressBarPaint.setStrokeWidth(CalculationUtil.convertDpToPx(
                widthInDp, getContext()));
        progressBarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        progressBarPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        outlinePaint = new Paint();
        outlinePaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        outlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        outlinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outlinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.black));
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        strokewidth = CalculationUtil.convertDpToPx(widthInDp, getContext());
        float scope = canvas.getWidth() + canvas.getHeight()
                + canvas.getHeight() + canvas.getWidth();
        float percent = (scope / 100) * Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(progress));
        float halfOfTheImage = canvas.getWidth() / 2;

        if (outline) {
            drawOutline();
        }

        if (isStartline()) {
            drawStartline();
        }

        if (showProgress) {
            drawPercent(percentSettings);
        }

        if (clearOnHundred && progress == 100.0) {
            return;
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        if (percent > halfOfTheImage) {
            paintFirstHalfOfTheTop(canvas);
            float second = percent - halfOfTheImage;

            if (second > canvas.getHeight()) {
                paintRightSide(canvas);
                float third = second - canvas.getHeight();

                if (third > canvas.getWidth()) {
                    paintBottomSide(canvas);
                    float forth = third - canvas.getWidth();

                    if (forth > canvas.getHeight()) {
                        paintLeftSide(canvas);
                        float fifth = forth - canvas.getHeight();

                        if (fifth == halfOfTheImage) {
                            paintSecondHalfOfTheTop(canvas);
                        } else {
                            path.moveTo(strokewidth, (strokewidth / 2));
                            path.lineTo(strokewidth + fifth, (strokewidth / 2));
                            canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
                        }
                    } else {
                        path.moveTo((strokewidth / 2), canvas.getHeight()
                                - strokewidth);
                        path.lineTo((strokewidth / 2), canvas.getHeight()
                                - forth);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
                    }

                } else {
                    path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() - strokewidth,
                            canvas.getHeight() - (strokewidth / 2));
                    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() - third, canvas.getHeight()
                            - (strokewidth / 2));
                    canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
                }
            } else {
                path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() - (strokewidth / 2), strokewidth);
                path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() - (strokewidth / 2), strokewidth
                        + second);
                canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
            }

        } else {
            path.moveTo(halfOfTheImage, strokewidth / 2);
            path.lineTo(halfOfTheImage + percent, strokewidth / 2);
            canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
        }

    }

    private void drawStartline() {
        Path outlinePath = new Path();
        outlinePath.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2, 0);
        outlinePath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2, strokewidth);
        canvas.drawPath(outlinePath, outlinePaint);
    }

    private void drawOutline() {
        Path outlinePath = new Path();
        outlinePath.moveTo(0, 0);
        outlinePath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0);
        outlinePath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        outlinePath.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
        outlinePath.lineTo(0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(outlinePath, outlinePaint);
    }

    public void paintFirstHalfOfTheTop(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2, strokewidth / 2);
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() + strokewidth, strokewidth / 2);
        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
    }

    public void paintRightSide(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() - (strokewidth / 2), strokewidth);
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() - (strokewidth / 2), canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
    }

    public void paintBottomSide(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth() - strokewidth, canvas.getHeight()
                - (strokewidth / 2));
        path.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight() - (strokewidth / 2));
        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
    }

    public void paintLeftSide(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo((strokewidth / 2), canvas.getHeight() - strokewidth);
        path.lineTo((strokewidth / 2), 0);
        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
    }

    public void paintSecondHalfOfTheTop(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(strokewidth, (strokewidth / 2));
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2, (strokewidth / 2));
        canvas.drawPath(path, progressBarPaint);
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        progressBarPaint.setColor(color);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @return the border
     */
    public float getWidthInDp() {
        return widthInDp;
    }

    /**
     * @return the border
     */
    public void setWidthInDp(int width) {
        this.widthInDp = width;
        progressBarPaint.setStrokeWidth(CalculationUtil.convertDpToPx(
                widthInDp, getContext()));
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isOutline() {
        return outline;
    }

    public void setOutline(boolean outline) {
        this.outline = outline;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isStartline() {
        return startline;
    }

    public void setStartline(boolean startline) {
        this.startline = startline;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void drawPercent(PercentStyle setting) {
        textPaint.setTextAlign(setting.getAlign());
        if (setting.getTextSize() == 0) {
            textPaint.setTextSize((canvas.getHeight() / 10) * 4);
        } else {
            textPaint.setTextSize(setting.getTextSize());
        }

        String percentString = new DecimalFormat("###").format(getProgress());
        if (setting.isPercentSign()) {
            percentString = percentString + percentSettings.getCustomText();
        }

        textPaint.setColor(percentSettings.getTextColor());

        canvas.drawText(
                percentString,
                canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint
                        .ascent()) / 2)), textPaint);
    }

    public boolean isShowProgress() {
        return showProgress;
    }

    public void setShowProgress(boolean showProgress) {
        this.showProgress = showProgress;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setPercentStyle(PercentStyle percentSettings) {
        this.percentSettings = percentSettings;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public PercentStyle getPercentStyle() {
        return percentSettings;
    }

    public void setClearOnHundred(boolean clearOnHundred) {
        this.clearOnHundred = clearOnHundred;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isClearOnHundred() {
        return clearOnHundred;
    }

}
```

above code is used to create square shape progressbar.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about adding this possibility to the library a few weeks ago. But the problem is, that I'm using a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) to calculate the progress around the image. And it seems to be difficult to work with paths and arcs when you only draw parts of it (the progress). But I did a bit of research and found these two ways on how you can draw rounded corners in general:

**Canvas - drawRoundRect**

This ([drawRoundRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)) is a method that the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) offers. But the problem here is that you need to give the method a rectangular which then gets rounded corners. As I said above, I'm using a path to draw the progress. So as far as I can see, you can't use that for my library code to add the possibility for rounded corners.

**Path - addArc / arcTo**

The path itself has two methods ([addArc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29) / [arcTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#arcTo%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29)) to work with arcs. But the problem is, that if you use them to apply some rounded corners to the path, you then have the problem of displaying the right percentage. Because you need a different way of calculating how far the arcs can go. So this would be a possibility, but it needs a rewrite/extension of my current progress-calculation.

Maybe there is another solution that I haven't thought off. But for the moment there is no supported way in the library to solve this. But you can try it with the two arc-methods from above. If you want that I (or somebody else) takes a try to add this to the library, please add a new [issue to the github repository](https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar/issues?state=open).